# Comparing strings always fails (string converted from Byte())

Tags: vb.net

My application is receiving commands via TCP, if I attempt to compare the command the comparison always fails.

The message is converted to a byte() and back but should compare ok in the below example? Or am I missing something?

```
Imports MyApp.Client

Public Class Form1
    Public Delegate Sub MessageReceivedHandler(ByVal message As String)

    Private Sub Message_Received(ByVal message As String)
        'update the display using invoke
        Invoke(New MessageReceivedHandler(AddressOf PrintToScreen), New Object() {message})
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintToScreen(ByVal msg As String)
        Select Case msg
            Case "#all"
                'Do Something
            Case Else
                'Do Something Else
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class


'Client class
Public Class Client
    Private _tcpClient As TcpClient
    Public Event MessageReceived As MessageReceivedHandler

    Public Sub Connect(ByVal address As IPAddress, ByVal port As Integer)
        _tcpClient = New TcpClient()
        Dim serverEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(address, port)
        _tcpClient.Connect(serverEndPoint)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf Read))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Send(ByVal buffer As Byte())
        _tcpClient.GetStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        _tcpClient.GetStream().Flush()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Read()
        Dim encoder As New ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        While True
            Try
                bytesRead = _tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, 4096)
                RaiseEvent MessageReceived(encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToString)
            Catch ex As IO.IOException
                Application.Exit()
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        _tcpClient.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The variable is a string containing the same text as the case, yet it fails the comparison:

[image: Msg Variable]

Comment: Could you please work this down to the smallest reproducible example?

Comment: What are the bytes that are read from the socket?  What is the resulting string after the ASCII encoding.  Which character(s) are different than what is expected?  As @asawyer said, please simplify this example to a few lines of code that reproduce the issue which don't involve the TCP communication at all.  For instance, your example could simply declare a byte array, fill it with expected hard-coded values, then ascii encode it to a string, and then compare it to the expected string.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is not the encoding at all, but rather that you are immediately raising the `MessageReceived` event before you make sure that you have received a complete message.  For instance, when you call `_tcpClient.GetStream().Read`, it may only return the first part of the message because that is all that has been received so far.

Comment: The message is received and passed via the event ok (added an image from the debug above) I created a project that raises the event by converting some text to a byte() and back (encoder.GetString) - this works fine.

Comment: hey @madlan, I found the similar case as yours .... the two Strings can't be successfully compared. The fact both are same "Date :" String. But different sources, for me the first String is taken from Word Document read, and another one is Variable String i defined. Seems both of them have a different type of string / encoding ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, the sending application was adding a vbNullChar to the end of the string before converting to a byte() and sending over. (Could not see a method to remove it from the string converted on the receiving end)

Comment: I was passing a full file path from MS Access (data actually held in SQL Server) to a COM object I had developed and my code was failing, this solution solved it for me so I ended up taking 1 less character. My final VB code was _sFileName = Mid(path, pos + 1, (Len(path) - pos - 1))_ where path was something like c:\temp\fred.jpg